# Is it possible to remove an inherited field/method in a child class/interface?

Tags: inheritance, typescript

Something along these lines:

```
interface A {
  a: number;
  x: any;
}

interface B extends A {
  b: number;
}

interface C {
  a: number;
  b: number;
}
```

So the `B` would be equal to `C` (omitting field `x` but still extending `A`). Is it possible? If so, how?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by this? It seems as though this defeats the whole point of inheritance.

Comment: @JamesHughes Most general definition of inheritance works with "modifies" not "only adds" in a context of members.

Comment: Yeah, you can modify them, but I'm fairly sure modification doesn't cover elimination

Comment: I understand under "modification" also removal or some form of hiding. You are describing subtyping, not inheritance.

From wiki: Inheritance should not be confused with subtyping.[3][4] In some languages inheritance and subtyping agree,[a] whereas in others they differ; in general, subtyping establishes an is-a relationship, whereas inheritance only reuses implementation and establishes a syntactic relationship, not necessarily a semantic relationship (inheritance does not ensure behavioral subtyping).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is impossible to remove an inherited field/method of an interface in TypeScript.

But you can overcome this via interfaces reengineering:

1. Extract base interface

   ```
   interface BaseA {
     a: number;
   }

   interface A extends Base A {
     x: any;
   }

   interface B extends A {
     b: number;
   }

   interface C extends BaseA {
     b: number;
   }
   ```

Both `C` and `B` will be castable to `BaseA`.

2. Use optional field

   ```
   interface A {
     a: number;
     x?: any;
   }

   interface B extends A {
     b: number;
   }

   interface C extends A {
     b: number;
   }
   ```

I'm sure there are other ways depending on the certain task context.

Comment: "Is impossible to remove an inherited field/method in a child class/interface due to inheritance concept principles." is untrue, inheritance is not subtyping. Inheritance is about code reuse and I am pretty sure that by definition of inheritance any type of change can occur in a child, even removal of a member. Second paragraph says it clearly: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't share your point of view. I've not found direct mention of member removal for a descendant interface. IMO interface is a contract declaration hence child interface should implement parent interface contract. If not, parent interface is not implemented.

Comment: You are confusing inheritance (some parts can be used in children) with sub-typing (child can act in a same role as a parent). From wiki: Inheritance should not be confused with subtyping.[3][4] In some languages inheritance and subtyping agree,[a] whereas in others they differ; in general, subtyping establishes an is-a relationship, whereas inheritance only reuses implementation and establishes a syntactic relationship, not necessarily a semantic relationship (inheritance does not ensure behavioral subtyping).

Comment: When you write "interface is a contract declaration hence child interface should implement parent interface contract" which is if I am not mistaken "Liskov substitution principle" which is sub-typing, not inheritance...

Comment: I don't like holywars :) For TypeScript as far as i know unswer for your question is "no", no matters how we understand interface inheritance. If somebody tells us how to answer yes on your question - I'll delete my answer and upvote the right one.

Comment: I am not saying it is possible in TS, just that you are describing sub-typing, not inheritance. And when generally speaking about inheritance it is possible to lose members in a child. Also I don't require `interface`, it can be a `class`. I just thought that since TS is based on JS which is unbelievably dynamic, such thing could be possible. (I was very surprised by for example implementation of `Partial`, didn't think they would add such wild things, that is the main reason I am asking about this form of inheritance.) No need to delete the answer, it could help somebody else :).

Comment: I've just removed controversial part of my answer, ok?

Answer (score 2):

here is another hacky way to deal with deleting child interface members:

```
interface Base {
  a: number;
  x?: any;
}

interface Child extends Base {
  x?: undefined;
}
```

this way, either the field `x` should not exist at all or if it does, it must be set to `undefined` which is as good as non-existent in most cases (unless you are trying to enumerate class members or do things like that).

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using typescripts [omit type-keys](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) noting that in typescript you can [extend multiple interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#extending-interfaces) at once.

> Typescript omit:
>
> Constructs a type by picking all properties from Type and then
> removing Keys (string literal or union of string literals).

Using your example:

```
interface A {
  a: number;
  x: any;
}

interface B extends A {
  b: number;
}

interface C extends Omit<A, 'x'>, Omit<B, 'x'> {}
```

Returns:

```
interface C {
  a: number;
  b: number;
}
```

[Working Typescript Playground demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4FgBQzlwBcyIArgLYBG0A3LvgB7FwgCedOAvrrqJLIhQAhZBAaQQAEwDOaTPWSViZKrVzccvcNHhJkAYVHiIU2QHlywMAB5UAGmQByBo4B8Di1etCHzt5g1cBAB7EGkwZEhw4kMAXnk8AmIARjsFJWQAJjSuHhwQsOCAGwgAOiLggHMACgADABUIcOQAd2CoAGtpQlqASg4C6WKyipqosH68oA)