# Making typescript inheriting interface member optional?

Tags: typescript, interface

So say I have this typescript interface

```
    interface IOptions{
        name: string;
        dob: date;
        gender: string;
    }
```

What then I have another interface that extends it

```
    interface ICustomOptions extends IOptions {
        height: number;
        weight: number;
        gender?: string;
    }
```

In the second interface I want a member that was required in the original interface to be optional in the second interface. Is there a way to do this without having to make a completely new interface?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41671281/is-it-possible-to-remove-an-inherited-field-method-in-a-child-class-interface/

Comment: that makes sense for removing a member from an interface but that not quite what I am trying to do. Does making it an optional instead of a required follow the same methodology?

Comment: I think for Typescript - yes - you cann't redeclare or modify base interface property in the inheritor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to follow the rules of polymorphism, you need the interface to be substitutable for its base interface.

This is pretty easy to do, you just haven't quite identified the base interface - because you are saying the `IOptions` is a specialisation because it requires gender... so it needs the same base interface as `ICustomOptions`.

```
interface ISimpleOptions {
    name: string;
    dob: number;
}

interface ICustomOptions extends ISimpleOptions {
    height: number;
    weight: number;
    gender?: string;
}

interface IOptions extends ISimpleOptions {
    gender: string;
}
```